# Python bisect behaviour with lists

Tags: python-3.x, bisect

I've been playing with bisect and I'm confused with the following behaviour:

**Input:**

```
test = 1
print(test)

bisect.insort([test], 6)
```

**Output:**

```
1
1
```

If I change when I define test as a list, I get a different response:

**Input:**

```
test = [1]
print(test)

bisect.insort(test, 6)
```

**Output:**

```
[1]
[1, 6]
```

Why does it do this?

Comment: Please include your code as text instead of screenshots

Comment: Sure. Will do that now. P.s. In the future, you could ask people to do this, and then give them a chance to respond before marking them down.

Comment: I did not downvote your question. In any case, you should not be bothered about downvotes. Ask good questions and give good answers, the points will come.

Comment: Okay, sorry for the assumption. I appreciate your help with the correct formatting, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bisect.insort appears to work "in place" on whatever is passed to it.  So, in the first example you pass it a list that is known only in the scope of the function `[test]` and it will insert into that list and make a list of `[1, 6]` but it does not return that result or modify the variable `test`--which is a good thing.